# Canon ftb shutter sticking and not returning, but returns when I loosen the lens

Tags: lens, canon, film

I have an old film Canon ftb. It was working fine but suddenly after taking a picture, the shutter fails to "spring back" and the viewfinder remains black. For a while I could give the camera a little knock and it would spring back. I can also loosen the lens a little and it springs back.

If I shoot without the lens on, it springs back no problem. So it's something to do with the lens.

What's happening here? Is it a lens or camera setting – something I did? Or is it just broken/needs cleaning? I can't seem to search the right terms to bring up this problem on an older film camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after I posted this I looked close at the mirror inside the body and it had slipped a little and was a little askew. Pushing this back into place fixed the problem. I'm guessing it was hitting the lens on its way back and that prevented it from closing.

Comment: It is time to take it to a repair shop for a C.L.A.  **C**lean, **L**ubricate, **A**djust.